# Codeigniter DB insert is not working properly(it inserts wrong value)

Tags: codeigniter

Currently, I am using Codeigniter 3.1.0. I am trying to insert data using $this->db->insert('table') in Model.

The problem is that when I try to insert a certain filed value as 0, it would not insert 0, instead, it inserts 10.

I have verified the value of the data and its type.

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
    $data['Vat'] = 0;

    foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value === null ) {
            continue;
        }
        $this->db->set($key, $value);
    }
    // $this->db->set('Vat', 0);

    $this->db->insert(self::TABLE);
    $q = $this->db->affected_rows();
    return $this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: Does the table column have a default value, and is the column itself have the same name (and case) as the data key you are using?

Comment: @gabe3886 

I don't have a default value for that column 'Vat'. The name of the column is different from the data key(the name of the column is 'Vat' and the data key is 'vat'). However, I have another columns that are all lower-cased and they dont have any problem with inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have look on your query by using last_query() function. just add below line after $this->db->insert(self::TABLE); and check whether query is perfect or not. You will get idea where you missing.

```
 echo $this->db->last_query(); die;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried your suggestion; I copied the query and executed it. It inserts correct value for vat. However, when I try to insert date through model, it inserts 10 instead of 0 which is desired value.

Answer (score 0):

The query was correct, however, after put function, update function(which I did not expect) was executed and it updated its value to 10. 
Thank you all for your responses.